# How to recover from accidental deletion of chrome extension developer account

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, google-account

We had a Google Chrome developer account and used this to publish several extensions to the Chrome Web Store.  Our IT department accidentally requested deletion of this account 11 days ago, which we just became aware of.  We were then unable to log in since the account no longer existed.  We then asked for a new account to be created under the original name and credentials, but our existing extensions do not show up on the new Developer Dashboard, even though the account name is the same as it used to be.

1. What happens to our existing extensions on the Web Store which are no longer associated with an active account?
2. If our existing extensions can no longer be obtained from the Web Store by users, what happens to an existing extension already installed on a user's Chrome browser?  Will it be unloaded automatically?
3. Is there a way to have the existing extensions transferred to the new account?  How does one go about contacting Google in order to formally request this?
4. If we need to republish these extensions, is there a way to use the existing extension IDs instead of creating new extension IDs?

Comment: Contact cws-developer-support via https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support.

Comment: Thank you.  We did that and got it taken care of.